# How to use a latex counter when its name depends on the result of other commands?

Tags: counters, roman-numerals

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{romannum}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{proximoMes}
\setcounter{proximoMes}{2}
\newcounter{qtdDiasI}
\setcounter{qtdDiasI}{5}

qtdDias\Romannum{\inteval{\value{proximoMes}-1}} % output: qtdDiasI

\Roman{qtdDias\Romannum{\inteval{\value{proximoMes}-1}}} % output: I

\end{document}
```

The \Roman{ } command on the last line does not show the counter value; instead, it shows "I". How can I get the Roman command to recognize the counter name and show the value "V"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). It just makes copy and pasting solutions easier when the code compiles.

Comment: You must clarify your question... Why do you use `\inteval`?

Comment: `\Roman{qtdDias\Roman{proximoMes}}` works. What is `\inteval`, and why do you need `\Romannum`?

Comment: @gernot  `\inteval` is originally from the `xfp` package but has been part of the kernel since June 2022.

Comment: @campa Thx. Should read the kernel code more often ...

Comment: What about `\addtocounter{proximoMes}{-1}\Roman{qtdDias\Roman{proximoMes}}`? The output `I` is just some spurious intermediate result that you get to see because the second line produces errors and can't be processed. Apparently your LaTeX systems hides these errors.

Comment: @JamesT Thanks for the suggestions. I've edited it as you suggested.

Comment: @gernot As I am using `\inteval` to perform mathematical operations with the counter value, it is necessary to use the `\Romannum` instead of the `\Roman`.

Comment: @gernot Oh, I learned that quite by accident myself, or maybe reading the LaTeX news...

Answer (score 3):

\Romannum is not expandable. But expl3 contains a function to convert an integer expression to a Roman numeral:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\inttoRoman{}
\cs_set_eq:NN\inttoRoman\int_to_Roman:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\newcounter{proximoMes}
\setcounter{proximoMes}{2}

\newcounter{qtdDiasI}
\setcounter{qtdDiasI}{5}

\Roman{qtdDias\inttoRoman{\value{proximoMes}-1}} % output: V

\end{document}
```

[image]